# Using temp tables with the same name in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables, temp

If I have a very basic stored procedure like this in SQL Server 2012:

```
Create Procedure [MyStoredProcedure] (@ input as int)

As


Select 1 as col1, 2 as Col2
Into #mytemp1

Drop Table #mytemp1

Select 3 as col1, 4 as Col2, 5 as Col3
Into #mytemp1

Drop Table #mytemp1
```

and I try and run it it fails with the error 'There is already an object named '#mytemp1' in the database.'
If this wasn't a stored procedure I could use GO after I initially drop the temp table. 
Is there a way around this?
Thanks

Comment: `(@ input as in)` What exactly are you trying to achieve here, other than giving us an example that doesn't show your problem because it's so syntactically invalid there are two errors in the space of 10 characters?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the same name twice instead of a different name for the second temp table?

Comment: @srutzky I guess the only reason is to save some time in building a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no explicit need to re-use the same temp table name, just use unique names for each temp table.

Well, *technically* you could do something like the following:

```
EXEC('
  Select 1 as col1, 2 as Col2
  Into #mytemp1

  something else related to #mytemp1
');

EXEC('
  Select 3 as col1, 4 as Col2, 5 as Col3
  Into #mytemp1

  something else related to #mytemp1
');
```

That would not fail as each temp table is isolated in a subprocess that is not parsed until the `EXEC` actually runs. And, the temp table disappears when the `EXEC` is finished (hence no need for the explicit `DROP` statements). But in most cases this is not a practical solution since the typical purpose of creating a temp table is to carry that data along to other operations, but here those temp tables are only viable within their particular `EXEC` context, so a bit limited.

Comment: Thanks. I did start to do that and I thought I'd end up having to do it but was curious as to whether it could be done.

Comment: @user3634559 Yeah, if it's a parse error then there is nothing you can do. For some parse errors you can encapsulate the query within an `EXEC('...')` but that won't work for temp tables since they will disappear as soon as that subprocess is finished.

Comment: @user3634559 I just updated my answer with an example of something that might work, but not terribly practical. But if it might work for your needs then certainly doesn't hurt to try, right?

Answer (score 1):

If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names.

```
Create Procedure [MyStoredProcedure] (@ input as in)

As
begin

Select 1 as col1, 2 as Col2
Into #mytemp1

Drop Table #mytemp1

Select 3 as col1, 4 as Col2, 5 as Col3
Into #mytemp1 // you cant use same **temp table** name in sp 

Drop Table #mytemp1
end
```

And this is not because the table has been dropped and can't be re-created; this code never gets executed, the parser actually sees you trying to create the same table twice

Answer (score 0):

check for Existence using `OBJECT_ID`

```
Create Procedure [MyStoredProcedure] (@ input as in)

As

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemp1') is not null
Drop Table #mytemp1

Select 1 as col1, 2 as Col2
Into #mytemp1 from mytable

--    perform your operations here


if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemp1') is not null
Drop Table #mytemp1

Select 3 as col1, 4 as Col2, 5 as Col3
Into #mytemp1 from mytable

--    perform your operations here
```

Comment: This will not work - I have tried to use this as a security blanket, and it still threw the same error